# Creating preformatted text and code in React app

Tags: reactjs, formatting

I am making a blog website in React in which user can submit code with other text. The entire code and other text will later be saved into the database. I am looking for the functionality like Stackoverflow's in which user can submit code and it is shown in the post in the original format.

I tried my best to search for the exact name of this functionality(My best guess is using LateX) but couldn't find any. So my exact question is what module or package do I need to represent the code submitted by the user in the original format as in Stackoverflow's question.

Please help me in the problem so I can get along with my work on my website.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research into the topic of markdown, I found that `react-markdown` is a npm module that can be used to create markdown in text string. It is almost similar to the one used in Stackoverflow. But the recent version seems to have some bug, so I used an older version(5.0.0). If you also want to include syntax highlighting, you can use `highlight.js`. It can be very easily included with `react-markdown`. Below is an example of `react-markdown`:

```
import React from "react";

import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";

export default class App3 extends React.Component {

  render(){
  var value='
    #Heading1
    <b>line break</b>
    _italics_';


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactMarkdown source={value} />
    </div>
  );}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can also use

```
dangerouslySetInnerHTML
```

if u don't to install 3rd libary